# Adding a button to a contact in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook

I have an app that registers a new URL scheme ('myapp://').

I want to have the address book keep track of addresses for contacts with the URL scheme like it does to e-mail, SMS, Facetime, phone, etc.

I want to have the contact info page have a button on it to launch my app and pass the 'myapp://' URL from the contact info page.

Is there a way to add a button to a contact in the Address Book like the 'Send Message' or 'Facetime' button?

Comment: Please post some code. Also, clarify the question - are you asking if you can modify the iPhone's native address book? Because the answer to that is 100% definitely no.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general one application can't change another; everything is sandboxed.

But you can add a URL and your URL scheme is just a normal URL, albeit one that doesn't work outside your iPhone. So it would appear as a link rather than a button, but it would work the same way.